# SQL Server: Running stored proceedure on remote server to delete data

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble running a SQL Server stored procedure on a remote server.

I have two servers, each running SQL Server, and each having databases with the same name and table structures. I want to truncate or drop a table on one server from the other server. When I try this is a SQL script on one server, I get an error that I have too many levels of specification of the table (`server.database.dbo.tablename`).

Only two levels are allowed for drop or truncate. I can do a delete on the table, but that takes a long time as there are a large number of rows in the table.

So I thought about running a stored procedure on the remote server. I run the remote stored procedure, but it it thinks I want to drop/truncate the table with the same name and database on the local server. I have tried various ways to refer to the remote server in the stored procedure, but I still get the local tables altered.

Here is the stored procedure as it exists at the moment. Got any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Have any ideas of another way to do this?

```
USE [PetroFlatTransfer]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DropTransferTables] 
    (@State VARCHAR(2))
AS
    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @TableName = '[sv9127].[PetroFlatTransfer].[dbo].[' + @State +'_ProductionHistory]';
    PRINT(@TableName);

    SET @SQL = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' +  @TableName
    PRINT(@SQL);
    EXEC (@SQL);
GO
```

Comment: Short useless answer: you need to look into `Linked Servers`. (I consider this a useless answer, because linked servers are an advanced and very complex subject. Hopefully someone else provides a more detailed reply.)

Answer (score 0):

try
to update other DB different server(s) you do connection string

use
OPENQUERY (Transact-SQL)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

connections OPENDATASOURCE 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx

- Permissions ...

you can use as well
sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

or Create Linked Servers (SQL Server Database Engine)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017